# Google Cloud Compute instance SSH key from metadata not added

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, metadata, google-compute-engine

I have been successfully adding SSH keys to newly spawned instances for a while, but all of a sudden it just won't work. They key isn't added to the target account (and the account isn't created if it doesn't exist). It still works fine for one of my projects, but it doesn't on the other which contains an adapted version of the code from the first. The steps both codes go through are as follows:

1. Create a disk from a snapshot.
2. Generate an RSA key pair.
3. Set the `ssh-keys` property in the metadata to the public key generated in the previous step in the format understood by Google Cloud (`<username>:ssh-rsa <key> <username>`).
4. Create the instance with the disk created in the first step and the metadata created in the third.

When I check out the instance data on the Google Cloud Console, it has the correct key assigned to the correct user in the SSH Keys section. However, when I SSH into the instance, the key hasn't been added to the `authorized_keys` file for that user. Just in case, I tried recreating the snapshot without that user so that the user can be created on the fly (which should work), but in that case the user isn't created.

In the end, Google Cloud just acts as if the SSH key isn't in the metadata, yet it is. I came accross [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516673/1657936) but can't seem to understand this part:

> As a direct consequence of that, the GCE platform takes care of placing/removing your ssh keys in the instance (...) ONLY when you do not specify your own keys (at instance creation or later). If you do, the GCE platform will consider the ssh key management as manual, and nothing will be kept in sync with the metadata store.

I don't see anything I'm doing that could be triggering it into manual mode, yet there obviously is an issue somewhere.

---

I just tried running the same process from an older snapshot and it worked flawlessly. I'll investigate further to see what causes this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the latest version of the [Guest Tools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment). Here is an example to install the latest version on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository universe

$ sudo apt install -y python-google-compute-engine python3-google-compute-engine google-compute-engine-oslogin gce-compute-image-packages
```

You can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment) more details and other OS.

Comment: It works on an older snapshot but not on the new one; I don't see how an older snapshot could have the guest tools (or a correct version of it) without the new version having it as well.

Comment: Please I would like to take a further look to this issue. I work for Google Cloud Support. Could you please open a private issue, an add your project number: issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164 Once we found the solution I will poste it so anyone can have the answer.

Comment: Just opened an issue with ID 74599290.

Comment: Hello @PLPeeters, per our discussion on issue tracker, we were not able to reproduce this behavior at the moment. If this happens again in the future, you may reopen a new issue tracker with detailed reproduction steps, and we will be happy to assist.

Comment: I wish I could have provided a minimal working example by now, but I've been a bit short on time these last few weeks. If I ever have some time to finally get to doing that, I will definitely be back in touch!

Comment: @minseong Given I didn't provide an answer here I don't think I ever figured out the root cause. I suppose I just switched to the older snapshot that worked and continued from there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this issue in a Debian-10 instance, however I was unable to reproduce. I created a new instance from a snapshot, and added a public key pair in the instance level metadata, in the section `SSH Keys`, then I tried to SSH using the SSH key and I was able to proceed.

---

This seems like an issue with the specific OS where you were unable to add the SSH key. In this scenario I suggest to gather the most information possible to debug the root cause.

I would recommend to verify if the Guest Environment was running [1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei), and/or install it manually [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#installing_guest_environment) as it make the communication with the [Metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) possible.

Also confirm that the VM is able to reach the Metadata Server `169.254.169.254` `metadata.google.internal`.

```
username@debian-10-000:~$ ping metadata.google.internal
PING metadata.google.internal (169.254.169.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from metadata.google.internal (169.254.169.254): icmp_seq=1     ttl=255 time=0.128 ms
```

[Related](https://serverfault.com/q/982517/535728).