# gcloud compute -- Instance ssh-key metadata ignored?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Starting with a service account JSON key, I attempt to add a throwaway "foo" ssh key to the `gcloud instances create` metadata and then connect to the instance using vanilla `ssh` and the throwaway key.

## Script

[here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/issues/884).

## Expected behavior

At boot, the account daemon would create a user account corresponding to the supplied ssh key.

## Observed behavior

- In the Cloud Console, the instance shows correctly applied ssh metadata.
- `ssh -i throwaway_private_key foo@${IP}` fails.
- Logs on the instance show:

```
Apr  6 16:58:34 sshkey-test-x0rmqgh7 sshd[497]: Invalid user foo from 209.6.197.126 port 39792
```

## How do I correctly trigger the account daemon?

If not through the metadata, then what?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173890/google-cloud-compute-instance-ssh-key-from-metadata-not-added

Comment: Show how you are adding the key to the metadata. The username is part of the data. This link might help you https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with a similar issue, there is a HUGE gotcha with `os-login` that can lead to the problem behavior.

In a nutshell, `os-login="TRUE"` can be (and is likely to be) set project-wide on GCE. If that's the case, then `ssh-key` metadata is ignored. I only discovered this [by chance](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118784701#comment3) from reading other issues in the Google bug tracker.

As soon as I toggled `os-login`, my issue went away.